# A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Tasker?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Recently updated an existing and working flutter project to null safety but I cannot get my sign-in logic with firebase to work. It fails with the below error

A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Tasker?'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Tasker?'.

```
Widget _getScreenId() {
    print('screen id');
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false).currentUserId =
              snapshot.data!.uid;
          return FutureBuilder(
              future: DatabaseService.getUserWithId(snapshot.data!.uid),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  print(snapshot.data);
                  Tasker? user = snapshot.data;
                  print("home");
                  return HomeScreen(user: user, currentUserId: '',);
                }
                return const SizedBox.shrink();
              });
        } else {
          return const LoginScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up with this which seems to work

```
 Widget _getScreenId() {
    // print('screen id');
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false).currentUserId =
              snapshot.data.uid;
          return FutureBuilder(
              future: DatabaseService.getUserWithId(snapshot.data.uid),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  Tasker user = snapshot.data;
                  // print("home");
                  return HomeScreen(currentUserId: user.id, user: user);
                }
                return const SizedBox.shrink();
              });
        } else {
          return const LoginScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

your snapshot by default returns a Object type try snapshot to AsyncSnapshot snapshot

```
Widget _getScreenId() {
    print('screen id');
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<Tasker> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false).currentUserId =
              snapshot.data!.uid;
          return FutureBuilder(
              future: DatabaseService.getUserWithId(snapshot.data!.uid),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  print(snapshot.data);
                  Tasker? user = snapshot.data;
                  print("home");
                  return HomeScreen(user: user, currentUserId: '',);
                }
                return const SizedBox.shrink();
              });
        } else {
          return const LoginScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```